# How to handle dynamic JSON data in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Let's say I have following JSON data:

```
[
  {
    "key": "Series 1",
    "values": [ [ 1025409600000 , 0] , [ 1028088000000 , -6.3382185140371] , [ 1030766400000 , -5.9507873460847] , [ 1033358400000 , -11.569146943813] , [ 1036040400000 , -5.4767332317425] , [ 1038632400000 , 0.50794682203014] , [ 1041310800000 , -5.5310285460542] , [ 1043989200000 , -5.7838296963382] , [ 1046408400000 , -7.3249341615649] , [ 1049086800000 , -6.7078630712489] , [ 1051675200000 , 0.44227126150934] , [ 1054353600000 , 7.2481659343222] , [ 1056945600000 , 9.2512381306992] , [ 1059624000000 , 11.341210982529] , [ 1062302400000 , 14.734820409020] , [ 1064894400000 , 12.387148007542] , [ 1067576400000 , 18.436471461827] , [ 1070168400000 , 19.830742266977] , [ 1072846800000 , 22.643205829887] , [ 1075525200000 , 26.743156781239] , [ 1078030800000 , 29.597478802228] , [ 1080709200000 , 30.831697585341] , [ 1083297600000 , 28.054068024708] , [ 1085976000000 , 29.294079423832] , [ 1088568000000 , 30.269264061274] , [ 1091246400000 , 24.934526898906] , [ 1093924800000 , 24.265982759406] , [ 1096516800000 , 27.217794897473] , [ 1099195200000 , 30.802601992077] , [ 1101790800000 , 36.331003758254] , [ 1104469200000 , 43.142498700060] , [ 1107147600000 , 40.558263931958] , [ 1109566800000 , 42.543622385800] , [ 1112245200000 , 41.683584710331] , [ 1114833600000 , 36.375367302328] , [ 1117512000000 , 40.719688980730] , [ 1120104000000 , 43.897963036919] , [ 1122782400000 , 49.797033975368] , [ 1125460800000 , 47.085993935989] , [ 1128052800000 , 46.601972859745] , [ 1130734800000 , 41.567784572762] , [ 1133326800000 , 47.296923737245] , [ 1136005200000 , 47.642969612080] , [ 1138683600000 , 50.781515820954] , [ 1141102800000 , 52.600229204305] , [ 1143781200000 , 55.599684490628] , [ 1146369600000 , 57.920388436633] , [ 1149048000000 , 53.503593218971] , [ 1151640000000 , 53.522973979964] , [ 1154318400000 , 49.846822298548] , [ 1156996800000 , 54.721341614650] , [ 1159588800000 , 58.186236223191] , [ 1162270800000 , 63.908065540997] , [ 1164862800000 , 69.767285129367] , [ 1167541200000 , 72.534013373592] , [ 1170219600000 , 77.991819436573] , [ 1172638800000 , 78.143584404990] , [ 1175313600000 , 83.702398665233] , [ 1177905600000 , 91.140859312418] , [ 1180584000000 , 98.590960607028] , [ 1183176000000 , 96.245634754228] , [ 1185854400000 , 92.326364432615] , [ 1188532800000 , 97.068765332230] , [ 1191124800000 , 105.81025556260] , [ 1193803200000 , 114.38348777791] , [ 1196398800000 , 103.59604949810] , [ 1199077200000 , 101.72488429307] , [ 1201755600000 , 89.840147735028] , [ 1204261200000 , 86.963597532664] , [ 1206936000000 , 84.075505208491] , [ 1209528000000 , 93.170105645831] , [ 1212206400000 , 103.62838083121] , [ 1214798400000 , 87.458241365091] , [ 1217476800000 , 85.808374141319] , [ 1220155200000 , 93.158054469193] , [ 1222747200000 , 65.973252382360] , [ 1225425600000 , 44.580686638224] , [ 1228021200000 , 36.418977140128] , [ 1230699600000 , 38.727678144761] , [ 1233378000000 , 36.692674173387] , [ 1235797200000 , 30.033022809480] , [ 1238472000000 , 36.707532162718] , [ 1241064000000 , 52.191457688389] , [ 1243742400000 , 56.357883979735] , [ 1246334400000 , 57.629002180305] , [ 1249012800000 , 66.650985790166] , [ 1251691200000 , 70.839243432186] , [ 1254283200000 , 78.731998491499] , [ 1256961600000 , 72.375528540349] , [ 1259557200000 , 81.738387881630] , [ 1262235600000 , 87.539792394232] , [ 1264914000000 , 84.320762662273] , [ 1267333200000 , 90.621278391889] , [ 1270008000000 , 102.47144881651] , [ 1272600000000 , 102.79320353429] , [ 1275278400000 , 90.529736050479] , [ 1277870400000 , 76.580859994531] , [ 1280548800000 , 86.548979376972] , [ 1283227200000 , 81.879653334089] , [ 1285819200000 , 101.72550015956] , [ 1288497600000 , 107.97964852260] , [ 1291093200000 , 106.16240630785] , [ 1293771600000 , 114.84268599533] , [ 1296450000000 , 121.60793322282] , [ 1298869200000 , 133.41437346605] , [ 1301544000000 , 125.46646042904] , [ 1304136000000 , 129.76784954301] , [ 1306814400000 , 128.15798861044] , [ 1309406400000 , 121.92388706072] , [ 1312084800000 , 116.70036100870] , [ 1314763200000 , 88.367701837033] , [ 1317355200000 , 59.159665765725] , [ 1320033600000 , 79.793568139753] , [ 1322629200000 , 75.903834028417] , [ 1325307600000 , 72.704218209157] , [ 1327986000000 , 84.936990804097] , [ 1330491600000 , 93.388148670744]]
  },
  {
    "key": "Series 2",
    "values": [ [ 1025409600000 , 0] , [ 1028088000000 , 0] , [ 1030766400000 , 0] , [ 1033358400000 , 0] , [ 1036040400000 , 0] , [ 1038632400000 , 0] , [ 1041310800000 , 0] , [ 1043989200000 , 0] , [ 1046408400000 , 0] , [ 1049086800000 , 0] , [ 1051675200000 , 0] , [ 1054353600000 , 0] , [ 1056945600000 , 0] , [ 1059624000000 , 0] , [ 1062302400000 , 0] , [ 1064894400000 , 0] , [ 1067576400000 , 0] , [ 1070168400000 , 0] , [ 1072846800000 , 0] , [ 1075525200000 , -0.049184266875945] , [ 1078030800000 , -0.10757569491991] , [ 1080709200000 , -0.075601531307242] , [ 1083297600000 , -0.061245277988149] , [ 1085976000000 , -0.068227316401169] , [ 1088568000000 , -0.11242758058502] , [ 1091246400000 , -0.074848439408270] , [ 1093924800000 , -0.11465623676497] , [ 1096516800000 , -0.24370633342416] , [ 1099195200000 , -0.21523268478893] , [ 1101790800000 , -0.37859370911822] , [ 1104469200000 , -0.41932884345151] , [ 1107147600000 , -0.45393735984802] , [ 1109566800000 , -0.50868179522598] , [ 1112245200000 , -0.48164396881207] , [ 1114833600000 , -0.41605962887194] , [ 1117512000000 , -0.48490348490240] , [ 1120104000000 , -0.55071036101311] , [ 1122782400000 , -0.67489170505394] , [ 1125460800000 , -0.74978070939342] , [ 1128052800000 , -0.86395050745343] , [ 1130734800000 , -0.78524898506764] , [ 1133326800000 , -0.99800440950854] , [ 1136005200000 , -1.1177951153878] , [ 1138683600000 , -1.4119975432964] , [ 1141102800000 , -1.2409959736465] , [ 1143781200000 , -1.3088936375431] , [ 1146369600000 , -1.5495785469683] , [ 1149048000000 , -1.1563414981293] , [ 1151640000000 , -0.87192471725994] , [ 1154318400000 , -0.84073995183442] , [ 1156996800000 , -0.88761892867370] , [ 1159588800000 , -0.81748513917485] , [ 1162270800000 , -1.2874081041274] , [ 1164862800000 , -1.9234702981339] , [ 1167541200000 , -1.8377768147648] , [ 1170219600000 , -2.7107654031830] , [ 1172638800000 , -2.6493268125418] , [ 1175313600000 , -3.0814553134551] , [ 1177905600000 , -3.8509837783574] , [ 1180584000000 , -5.2919167850718] , [ 1183176000000 , -5.2297750650773] , [ 1185854400000 , -3.9335668501451] , [ 1188532800000 , -2.3695525190114] , [ 1191124800000 , -2.3084243151854] , [ 1193803200000 , -3.0753680726738] , [ 1196398800000 , -2.2346609938962] , [ 1199077200000 , -3.0598810361615] , [ 1201755600000 , -1.8410154270386] , [ 1204261200000 , -1.6479442038620] , [ 1206936000000 , -1.9293858622780] , [ 1209528000000 , -3.0769590460943] , [ 1212206400000 , -4.2423933501421] , [ 1214798400000 , -2.6951491617768] , [ 1217476800000 , -2.8981825939957] , [ 1220155200000 , -2.9662727940324] , [ 1222747200000 , 0.21556750497498] , [ 1225425600000 , 2.6784995167088] , [ 1228021200000 , 4.1296711248958] , [ 1230699600000 , 3.7311068218734] , [ 1233378000000 , 4.7695330866954] , [ 1235797200000 , 5.1919133040990] , [ 1238472000000 , 4.1025856045660] , [ 1241064000000 , 2.8498939666225] , [ 1243742400000 , 2.8106017222851] , [ 1246334400000 , 2.8456526669963] , [ 1249012800000 , 0.65563070754298] , [ 1251691200000 , -0.30022343874633] , [ 1254283200000 , -1.1600358228964] , [ 1256961600000 , -0.26674408835052] , [ 1259557200000 , -1.4693389757812] , [ 1262235600000 , -2.7855421590594] , [ 1264914000000 , -1.2668244065703] , [ 1267333200000 , -2.5537804115548] , [ 1270008000000 , -4.9144552474502] , [ 1272600000000 , -6.0484408234831] , [ 1275278400000 , -3.3834349033750] , [ 1277870400000 , -0.46752826932523] , [ 1280548800000 , -1.8030186027963] , [ 1283227200000 , -0.99623230097881] , [ 1285819200000 , -3.3475370235594] , [ 1288497600000 , -3.8187026520342] , [ 1291093200000 , -4.2354146250353] , [ 1293771600000 , -5.6795404292885] , [ 1296450000000 , -6.2928665328172] , [ 1298869200000 , -6.8549277434419] , [ 1301544000000 , -6.9925308360918] , [ 1304136000000 , -8.3216548655839] , [ 1306814400000 , -7.7682867271435] , [ 1309406400000 , -6.9244213301058] , [ 1312084800000 , -5.7407624451404] , [ 1314763200000 , -2.1813149077927] , [ 1317355200000 , 2.9407596325999] , [ 1320033600000 , -1.1130607112134] , [ 1322629200000 , -2.0274822307752] , [ 1325307600000 , -1.8372559072154] , [ 1327986000000 , -4.0732815531148] , [ 1330491600000 , -6.4417038470291]]
  },
  {
    "key": "Series 3",
    "values": [ [ 1025409600000 , 0] , [ 1028088000000 , -6.3382185140371] , [ 1030766400000 , -5.9507873460847] , [ 1033358400000 , -11.569146943813] , [ 1036040400000 , -5.4767332317425] , [ 1038632400000 , 0.50794682203014] , [ 1041310800000 , -5.5310285460542] , [ 1043989200000 , -5.7838296963382] , [ 1046408400000 , -7.3249341615649] , [ 1049086800000 , -6.7078630712489] , [ 1051675200000 , 0.44227126150934] , [ 1054353600000 , 7.2481659343222] , [ 1056945600000 , 9.2512381306992] , [ 1059624000000 , 11.341210982529] , [ 1062302400000 , 14.734820409020] , [ 1064894400000 , 12.387148007542] , [ 1067576400000 , 18.436471461827] , [ 1070168400000 , 19.830742266977] , [ 1072846800000 , 22.643205829887] , [ 1075525200000 , 26.693972514363] , [ 1078030800000 , 29.489903107308] , [ 1080709200000 , 30.756096054034] , [ 1083297600000 , 27.992822746720] , [ 1085976000000 , 29.225852107431] , [ 1088568000000 , 30.156836480689] , [ 1091246400000 , 24.859678459498] , [ 1093924800000 , 24.151326522641] , [ 1096516800000 , 26.974088564049] , [ 1099195200000 , 30.587369307288] , [ 1101790800000 , 35.952410049136] , [ 1104469200000 , 42.723169856608] , [ 1107147600000 , 40.104326572110] , [ 1109566800000 , 42.034940590574] , [ 1112245200000 , 41.201940741519] , [ 1114833600000 , 35.959307673456] , [ 1117512000000 , 40.234785495828] , [ 1120104000000 , 43.347252675906] , [ 1122782400000 , 49.122142270314] , [ 1125460800000 , 46.336213226596] , [ 1128052800000 , 45.738022352292] , [ 1130734800000 , 40.782535587694] , [ 1133326800000 , 46.298919327736] , [ 1136005200000 , 46.525174496692] , [ 1138683600000 , 49.369518277658] , [ 1141102800000 , 51.359233230659] , [ 1143781200000 , 54.290790853085] , [ 1146369600000 , 56.370809889665] , [ 1149048000000 , 52.347251720842] , [ 1151640000000 , 52.651049262704] , [ 1154318400000 , 49.006082346714] , [ 1156996800000 , 53.833722685976] , [ 1159588800000 , 57.368751084016] , [ 1162270800000 , 62.620657436870] , [ 1164862800000 , 67.843814831233] , [ 1167541200000 , 70.696236558827] , [ 1170219600000 , 75.281054033390] , [ 1172638800000 , 75.494257592448] , [ 1175313600000 , 80.620943351778] , [ 1177905600000 , 87.289875534061] , [ 1180584000000 , 93.299043821956] , [ 1183176000000 , 91.015859689151] , [ 1185854400000 , 88.392797582470] , [ 1188532800000 , 94.699212813219] , [ 1191124800000 , 103.50183124741] , [ 1193803200000 , 111.30811970524] , [ 1196398800000 , 101.36138850420] , [ 1199077200000 , 98.665003256909] , [ 1201755600000 , 87.999132307989] , [ 1204261200000 , 85.315653328802] , [ 1206936000000 , 82.146119346213] , [ 1209528000000 , 90.093146599737] , [ 1212206400000 , 99.385987481068] , [ 1214798400000 , 84.763092203314] , [ 1217476800000 , 82.910191547323] , [ 1220155200000 , 90.191781675161] , [ 1222747200000 , 66.188819887335] , [ 1225425600000 , 47.259186154933] , [ 1228021200000 , 40.548648265024] , [ 1230699600000 , 42.458784966634] , [ 1233378000000 , 41.462207260082] , [ 1235797200000 , 35.224936113579] , [ 1238472000000 , 40.810117767284] , [ 1241064000000 , 55.041351655012] , [ 1243742400000 , 59.168485702020] , [ 1246334400000 , 60.474654847301] , [ 1249012800000 , 67.306616497709] , [ 1251691200000 , 70.539019993440] , [ 1254283200000 , 77.571962668603] , [ 1256961600000 , 72.108784451998] , [ 1259557200000 , 80.269048905849] , [ 1262235600000 , 84.754250235173] , [ 1264914000000 , 83.053938255703] , [ 1267333200000 , 88.067497980334] , [ 1270008000000 , 97.556993569060] , [ 1272600000000 , 96.744762710807] , [ 1275278400000 , 87.146301147104] , [ 1277870400000 , 76.113331725206] , [ 1280548800000 , 84.745960774176] , [ 1283227200000 , 80.883421033110] , [ 1285819200000 , 98.377963136001] , [ 1288497600000 , 104.16094587057] , [ 1291093200000 , 101.92699168281] , [ 1293771600000 , 109.16314556604] , [ 1296450000000 , 115.31506669000] , [ 1298869200000 , 126.55944572261] , [ 1301544000000 , 118.47392959295] , [ 1304136000000 , 121.44619467743] , [ 1306814400000 , 120.38970188330] , [ 1309406400000 , 114.99946573061] , [ 1312084800000 , 110.95959856356] , [ 1314763200000 , 86.186386929240] , [ 1317355200000 , 62.100425398325] , [ 1320033600000 , 78.680507428540] , [ 1322629200000 , 73.876351797642] , [ 1325307600000 , 70.866962301942] , [ 1327986000000 , 80.863709250982] , [ 1330491600000 , 86.946444823715]]
  },
  {
    "key": "Series 4",
    "values": [ [ 1025409600000 , -7.0674410638835] , [ 1028088000000 , -14.663359292964] , [ 1030766400000 , -14.104393060540] , [ 1033358400000 , -23.114477037218] , [ 1036040400000 , -16.774256687841] , [ 1038632400000 , -11.902028464000] , [ 1041310800000 , -16.883038668422] , [ 1043989200000 , -19.104223676831] , [ 1046408400000 , -20.420523282736] , [ 1049086800000 , -19.660555051587] , [ 1051675200000 , -13.106911231646] , [ 1054353600000 , -8.2448460302143] , [ 1056945600000 , -7.0313058730976] , [ 1059624000000 , -5.1485118700389] , [ 1062302400000 , -3.0011028761469] , [ 1064894400000 , -4.1367265281467] , [ 1067576400000 , 1.5425209565025] , [ 1070168400000 , 2.7673533607299] , [ 1072846800000 , 7.7077114755360] , [ 1075525200000 , 9.7565015112434] , [ 1078030800000 , 11.396888609473] , [ 1080709200000 , 10.013964745578] , [ 1083297600000 , 8.0558890950562] , [ 1085976000000 , 9.6081966657458] , [ 1088568000000 , 11.918590426432] , [ 1091246400000 , 7.9945345523982] , [ 1093924800000 , 8.3201276776796] , [ 1096516800000 , 9.8283954846342] , [ 1099195200000 , 11.527125859650] , [ 1101790800000 , 16.413657596527] , [ 1104469200000 , 20.393798297928] , [ 1107147600000 , 17.456308413907] , [ 1109566800000 , 20.087778400999] , [ 1112245200000 , 17.988336990817] , [ 1114833600000 , 15.378490151331] , [ 1117512000000 , 19.474322935730] , [ 1120104000000 , 20.013851070354] , [ 1122782400000 , 24.749943726975] , [ 1125460800000 , 23.558710274826] , [ 1128052800000 , 24.558915040889] , [ 1130734800000 , 22.355860488034] , [ 1133326800000 , 27.138026265756] , [ 1136005200000 , 27.202220808591] , [ 1138683600000 , 31.219437344964] , [ 1141102800000 , 31.392355525125] , [ 1143781200000 , 33.373099232542] , [ 1146369600000 , 35.095277582309] , [ 1149048000000 , 30.923356507615] , [ 1151640000000 , 31.083717332561] , [ 1154318400000 , 31.290690671561] , [ 1156996800000 , 34.247769216679] , [ 1159588800000 , 37.411073177620] , [ 1162270800000 , 42.079177096411] , [ 1164862800000 , 44.978191659648] , [ 1167541200000 , 46.713271025310] , [ 1170219600000 , 49.203892437699] , [ 1172638800000 , 46.684723471826] , [ 1175313600000 , 48.385458973500] , [ 1177905600000 , 54.660197840305] , [ 1180584000000 , 60.311838415602] , [ 1183176000000 , 57.583282204682] , [ 1185854400000 , 52.425398898751] , [ 1188532800000 , 54.663538086985] , [ 1191124800000 , 60.181844325224] , [ 1193803200000 , 62.877219773621] , [ 1196398800000 , 55.760611512951] , [ 1199077200000 , 54.735280367784] , [ 1201755600000 , 45.495912959474] , [ 1204261200000 , 40.934919015876] , [ 1206936000000 , 40.303777633187] , [ 1209528000000 , 47.403740368773] , [ 1212206400000 , 49.951960898839] , [ 1214798400000 , 37.534590035098] , [ 1217476800000 , 36.405758293321] , [ 1220155200000 , 38.545373001858] , [ 1222747200000 , 26.106358664455] , [ 1225425600000 , 4.2658006768744] , [ 1228021200000 , -3.5517839867557] , [ 1230699600000 , -2.0878920761513] , [ 1233378000000 , -10.408879093829] , [ 1235797200000 , -19.924242196038] , [ 1238472000000 , -12.906491912782] , [ 1241064000000 , -3.9774866468346] , [ 1243742400000 , 1.0319171601402] , [ 1246334400000 , 1.3109350357718] , [ 1249012800000 , 9.1668309061935] , [ 1251691200000 , 13.121178985954] , [ 1254283200000 , 17.578680237511] , [ 1256961600000 , 14.971294355085] , [ 1259557200000 , 21.551327027338] , [ 1262235600000 , 24.592328423819] , [ 1264914000000 , 20.158087829555] , [ 1267333200000 , 24.135661929185] , [ 1270008000000 , 31.815205405903] , [ 1272600000000 , 34.389524768466] , [ 1275278400000 , 23.785555857522] , [ 1277870400000 , 17.082756649072] , [ 1280548800000 , 25.248007727100] , [ 1283227200000 , 19.415179069165] , [ 1285819200000 , 30.413636349327] , [ 1288497600000 , 35.357952964550] , [ 1291093200000 , 35.886413535859] , [ 1293771600000 , 45.003601951959] , [ 1296450000000 , 48.274893564020] , [ 1298869200000 , 53.562864914648] , [ 1301544000000 , 54.108274337412] , [ 1304136000000 , 58.618190111927] , [ 1306814400000 , 56.806793965598] , [ 1309406400000 , 54.135477252994] , [ 1312084800000 , 50.735258942442] , [ 1314763200000 , 42.208170945813] , [ 1317355200000 , 31.617916826724] , [ 1320033600000 , 46.492005006737] , [ 1322629200000 , 46.203116922145] , [ 1325307600000 , 47.541427643137] , [ 1327986000000 , 54.518998440993] , [ 1330491600000 , 61.099720234693]]
  }
]
```

Key values can be changed dynamically (ie `Series 1` might be missing, or instead that we can have `Series 10`, or might have only `Series 1` and `Series 2` etc). Values are pairs of unix timestamp and Y axis value. 
I need to display each dataset (for each key), so in this case I need 4 graphs, with appropriate labels (Series 1, Series 2, and so on).
Can someone point me to right way to parse that type of data? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From the API Reference, for `selection.data([values[, key]])`

> If a key function is not specified, then the first datum in the specified array is assigned to the first element in the current selection, the second datum to the second selected element, and so on.

So, your data join will look something like this:

```
var ele = 'g';

var join = selection.selectAll(ele).data(JSON, function(d) { return d.key });
join.enter().append('g');
join.exit().remove();
```

If multiple elements in your JSON array have missing or null keys, they will overwrite each other because `undefined === undefined` and `null === null`. Assuming each element is unique, this is probably not the desired behavior - so you should normalize your data to prevent this from happening.

How you handle normalizing your data is really up to you - you just have to make sure that the new key that you assign doesn't overwrite existing keys. One possible solution: note that `NaN !== NaN` so setting `d.key = NaN` will prevent these elements from overwriting one another.

```
for (var i = 0, l = JSON.length; i < l; i++ )
  if (JSON[i].key == null) JSON[i].key = NaN;
```

Obviously, with a technique like this, you would need to account for that when displaying the key:

```
join.select('text').text(function(d) { 
  isNaN(d.key) && (typeof d.key === 'number') ? 'No key' : d.key; 
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, unfortunately still don't know how to implement that to draw graphs :(